# How to add extra parameters in alongside to Points in exam class?

Tags: macros, exam

I am a novice to latex. I have requirement while setting question paper. Apart from Marks or points that could be added to the right side of each question, I need to place Course Outcomes (CO) & Bloom's Taxonomy (BT) levels to each question that should appear in parallel to Marks/Points on the right side using Exam package.

A template like this is what I need

`\question[<M>,<BT>,<CO>] <question>`

Eg.,
`\question[10,1,4] what is the area of the circle, if the radius is 5 cm,?`

so that produces an output like

1. what is the area of the circle, if the radius is 5 cm,?  (10)(1)(4)

Is there is any other package to implement my requirement??
CO PO in an exam paper.

[image]

Assume that I have 4 COs in a subject and the question paper max. mark is 50 and a student has scored 45 Marks.

[image]

@Andrew, The tables and the questions that I posted are basically from MS word document, and they are static. We need to do the entry manually. What I need was to automate the entries that I have made for COs in question paper to get added up and generate a table containing each CO Maximum marks (at the denominator). So I need a command like `\question[<M=10>,<BT=1,3>,<CO1=3,CO4=7>]` , which indicates that the max mark of this question is 10 and it contains Bloom Taxonomy levels 1,3 and there are two COs, in which CO1 carries max of 3 Marks and CO4 carries max of 7 Marks. Finally, the table should show the CO1 to CO4 elements and the max marks of each CO's should be added from each question. consider that I have 5 questions and out of 5, only one question has CO1 component with a max of 3 Marks, then while the table is generated, it should contain an entry for CO1 as /3 in the denominator.

Also if there is any way in the preamble to define the number of COs(say in my case it is 4), it would be very great.

I guess it is a pretty difficult job, but that would serve us a lot.

---

I am attaching the template of the question paper I needed in latex.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Producing this output with the exam class is non-trivial. This aside, do the COs correspond in any way to the questions? Further, are the 11/11, 13/13, 12/11 and 9/15 the student marks? If not then what are they? Sorry if I am being slow but without some explanation of the relationship between `\question[<M>,<BT>,<CO>]` and the final table I can't help. I think that you need to give "mock code" for producing the screen shot above. This said, perhaps you should just typeset everything inside a normal latex table as it will take some effort for some noe to do this for you, for no obvious gain.

Comment: @Andrew, The tables and the questions that I posted are basically from MS word document, and they are static. We need to do the entry manually. What I need was to automate the entries that I have made for COs in question paper to get added up and generate a table containing each CO Maximum marks (at the denominator)

Comment: As you say, it is quite a bit of work. I can see a way to do this, although making it compatible with the exam class seems difficult since I don't use it and hence don't know how it works. These points aside, (1) should the table appear at the end of the document, and (2), can  explain how are the numerators calculated? It sounds a little like the numerators are the student's marks, in which case perhaps they should be left blank, although a mark of 12/11 seems unlikely.

Comment: @Andrew, Yes the table should appear at the end of the document and the numerator should be blank. I prefer to use Exam class just because it automatically places the Marks to the each question and since it already has built in mechanism to produce the grade chart, it might be enough to modify only the code that is responsible.

Comment: You can get professional and personal support from everal people worldwide. The given problem is a bit too complex for the site, i'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** New answer based on extra information in the question

I don't use the [exam](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) class so I don't really appreciate its inner workings, however, according to the manual you can change how a question is formatted using `\qformat`.

To cope with the extra data that you want to incorporate (the BTs, Ms and COs), I think that you need to define a new macro that will process these. The code below defines a `\Question` macro that takes three arguments: `M`, `BT` and `CO` and does something that is in the spirit of what you want -- you should be able to tweak the code for your precise requirements.

The idea is that `\Question` defines macros `\theM`, `\theBRT` and `\theCO` and `\qformat` uses these to print the question by "calling" `\question`. The only complicated bit is in keeping track of the different course outcomes. To do this, `\Question` assumes that `CO` is given as a comma separated list. By looping over the entries of this list it (implicitly) defines macros `\COmax`, for the number of course outcomes (this is arbitrary), and `\CO1`, `\CO2`, ..., which count the number of times the given course outcome is used. Finally, there is a `\printCourseOutcomes` macro that generates a table of the number of course outcomes of each type.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% question format used by exams
\qformat{Question \thequestion \dotfill \theM\theBT\theCO}

\def\COmax{0}% number of course outcomes: will automatically track the number specified
\def\Question[#1,#2,#3]{
    \def\theM{\textbf{M}:#1\space}
    \def\theBT{\textbf{BT}:#2\space}
    \def\theCO{\textbf{CO}:#3}
    \foreach \co in {#3} {
         \ifcsdef{CO\co}{\csxdef{CO\co}{\the\numexpr\csuse{CO\co}+1\relax}}% add 1 if exists
                                       {\csxdef{CO\co}{1}}% set to 1 if does not exist
         \ifnum\co>\COmax\xdef\COmax{\co}\fi% make sure \COmax is big enough for all specified COs
    }
    \question% start the question
}
\newcommand\printCourseOutcomes{%
\bigskip
   \bgroup
   \def\tableRow{\\\toprule Course outcome}
   \foreach \co in {1,...,\COmax}{\xappto\tableRow{& CO\co}}
   \appto\tableRow{\\\midrule}
   \foreach \co in {1,...,\COmax}{\xappto\tableRow{& \csuse{CO\co}}}
   \tabular{l*{\COmax}c}\tableRow\\\bottomrule\endtabular\egroup
}
\addpoints

\begin{document}
\gradetable[h][questions]

\begin{questions}
  \Question[10,4,1,2] What is the area of the circle, if the radius is 5 cm?
  \Question[2,3,2] When is a frog?
\end{questions}

\printCourseOutcomes

\end{document}
```

and here is the output that it produces:

[image]

The format of the question can easily be tweaked to your needs by modifying the definitions of `\theM`, `\theBT`, `\theCO` and the `\qformat` command. Less clear to me is how you want to assign points to each question, but I assume that you do want to this since the OP mentions creating a grade table.

**Original answer**

If you don't need the exam class to add up the points in the "exam" then you can fudge this with existing functionality in the class:

```
\documentclass[]{exam}
\pointsinrightmargin

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question[10)(4)(2] What is the area of the circle, if the radius is 5 cm?
  \question[2)(3)(4] When is a frog?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

If you want to automatically add up the points for each question then this simple-minded approach will not work.

Comment: Thank's Andrew, it really gives some solution to the present situation, but there is a requirement of adding the CO (Course Outcome) Marks. Let us assume, that there are 4 COs in a subject, and each question can carry 1 or more COs. Now if 1 question contains 2 COs and a total of 10 Marks, is there is any way I could assign 6 for one of the CO and 4 for the other. At the end, can we add all the marks of particular CO as a grade table?

Comment: @Narashimaraja It is not clear to me how you want to "assign 6 for one of the CO and 4 for the other". Is this via the  `\questio[...]` commands above? If you add precise details of what you want to the question, including what the grade table should look like, then I will update my answer to give you a way of doing this. In particular, please tell me if there is already a command for grade tables in the exam class (I don't use this class but I can hack it).

Comment: I have re-edited my post for the requirement what I have asked.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I have re-edited my post for the requirement what I have asked for.

Comment: @Narashimaraja I have written a new answer that I think does what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Is there is any way to specify possibility of specifying CO marks like, <CO1=4> and then add up all the marks that correspond to a particular CO? But I need to thank a lot Andrew for the effort you are putting.

Comment: @Narashimaraja Yes, this is possible but it will require some reworking, so it would have been better if you had said this earlier. Do you want something similar with the `M`s and `BT`s? Should the marks for each `CO` be displayed on the question? Should the sum of the different `CO` become the points for the`\question`? Please think about what you want and edit your question to describe this carefully. To constantly change what you are asking for is not really the idea of the site. Btw, the standard way of thanking on TeX.SX is to up-vote and award green ticks.

Comment: I am new to this site and this was my 2nd post in this forum. Sorry for my blunder. As you said the CO marks need not be displayed in Questions, but the CO levels and BT levels, along with marks of each question are needed. At the end, I need both the marks of each question and the cumulative marks for each row in two different table.

Comment: @Narashimaraja Please add clear details as to what the inputs and output should look like, with an example, and then I will take a look at it. Since you mentioned grade tables your [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) should include this too so that it is clear what you want.

Comment: I have attached the question paper for the template. The question paper is prepared using MS word. All the entries are made manually. But I want to work with latex and with automated table generation at the end of the paper.

Comment: @Narashimaraja TeX.SX is not meant to be a service where people solve latex problems for you. I have asked repeatedly for you to provide details as to what the input and output look like but it seems that the best you can do is put up images of existing word documents. it is not clear what if anything you have done towards solving the problem yourself, so i will vote to close this question.